# export just a variable not the entire file - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I am working on a project which requires to use node with **ES6** alongside **Mocha**. So I came across a small issue, When I export a variable from one file to another, It actually exports the entire file! However I just want the variable to be exported.

Simply said, I want the updated value of **x** but doesn't want **foo.js** to run the **Test Suit**(function *doubleX*). How can I achieve this or what is wrong with my approach?

```
// foo.js
import {x} from './bar.js'
console.log(x);

// bar.js
export var x = 5;

// Test Suit Function
function doubleX(){
    describe("Test Suit", function(){
        // Few Calculations & Updated Variable
            x += x;
        // Some Test Case
        it("Test Case", function(){

        })
    })
}
// Need to run test suit by bar.js not by foo.js
doubleX();
console.log(x);
```

*Mocha scripts*:

```
"scripts": {
    "foo": "node_modules/.bin/mocha -bail --compilers js:babel-core/register -r jsdom-global/register foo.js",
    "bar": "node_modules/.bin/mocha -bail --compilers js:babel-core/register -r jsdom-global/register bar.js",
}
```

When I use `npm run foo`

*Actual Output*:

```
10
10


(node:4981) DeprecationWarning: "--compilers" will be removed in a future version of Mocha; see https://git.io/vdcSr for more info
  Test Suit
    ✓ Test Case


  1 passing (8ms)
```

*Expected Output*:

```
10
```

Comment: It seems you have removed the extra `console.log` statement from your bar.js file, so the actual output can't be `10` twice.

Answer (score 1):

By importing the `bar.js` file Node is running through the entire file.
Since you're calling the `doubleX` function and `console.log`ging in `bar.js`, the value of `x` is altered and extra logs are being spit out.

Instead, you should change your `doubleX` function so it takes a parameter and then returns with a value of the parameter plus itself. Also you probably shouldn't call the function directly after defining it.

```
function doubleNum(num){
  return num + num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `doubleX()` is not exported you can test this by

```
// foo.js
import {x} from './bar.js'
console.log(x);
doubleX(); // would give error
```

It is being called inside bar.js hence it is executed

Comment: I am using **Mocha** to test these scripts.Earlier, I tried to explain with the simplest possible example without mocha scripts. Its still executes `doubleX()` function & `console("Inside doubleX")`. I have updated the question with mocha scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In your bar.js file use the following code:

```
var doubleX = function(x) {
   x += x;
   return x; // or you can return the above statement too using return x+= x;
};
doubleX(5);

module.exports = doubleX;
```

In your foo.js file

```
import {doubleX} from './bar.js'
console.log(doubleX);
```

Comment: I got your point, I have updated the question to make it more meaningful, I hope you will get the my exact question this time.